# Optimizing Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, memory, nginx, optimization

I've been reading multiple optimization guide for apache and found a lot of data (Although I have no idea what is the experience of the authors).

I have a production server with apache 2.2.3, MySQL 5.1.36, Centos 5.3, nginx to act as a reverse proxy server (and handle the static files).

My main problem is I have around 10 processes of httpd each taking up to 56-60MB RAM, and every 15 minutes I fire 10 php processes via a crond (each taking up 30MB aswell).

Basically I am operating with the default httpd.conf (yeah I know, this is bad), I have just tweaked the MPM max clients and other properties controlling how many clients shoudld be forked, and installed nginx to reduce load on apache.

I'd be happy what kind of optimization I could do to my httpd (I know I should be unloading lot of modules but I'm kinda scared than removing something could break my application).

```
21969 root      16   0  145m  30m 6872 S  1.3  0.9   0:00.75 php                                                                                                                 
 6031 apache    16   0  289m  59m  35m S  1.0  1.3   0:05.01 httpd
```

Another output for one of the process I am running:

```
[root@www /]# pmap -d 6031
6031:   /usr/sbin/httpd
Address           Kbytes Mode  Offset           Device    Mapping
00002b8b622e4000     308 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 httpd
00002b8b62331000     100 rw-s- 0000000000000000 000:00023   [ anon ]
00002b8b6234a000      32 rw-s- 0000000000000000 000:00023   [ anon ]
00002b8b62531000      16 rw--- 000000000004d000 008:00003 httpd
00002b8b62535000      12 rw--- 00002b8b62535000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b62538000     112 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 ld-2.5.so
00002b8b62554000       4 rw--- 00002b8b62554000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b6255a000       4 rw--- 00002b8b6255a000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b62753000       4 r---- 000000000001b000 008:00003 ld-2.5.so
00002b8b62754000       4 rw--- 000000000001c000 008:00003 ld-2.5.so
00002b8b62755000     520 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libm-2.5.so
00002b8b627d7000    2044 ----- 0000000000082000 008:00003 libm-2.5.so
00002b8b629d6000       4 r---- 0000000000081000 008:00003 libm-2.5.so
00002b8b629d7000       4 rw--- 0000000000082000 008:00003 libm-2.5.so
00002b8b629d8000     108 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libpcre.so.0.0.1
00002b8b629f3000    2048 ----- 000000000001b000 008:00003 libpcre.so.0.0.1
00002b8b62bf3000       4 rw--- 000000000001b000 008:00003 libpcre.so.0.0.1
00002b8b62bf4000      84 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libselinux.so.1
00002b8b62c09000    2048 ----- 0000000000015000 008:00003 libselinux.so.1
00002b8b62e09000       8 rw--- 0000000000015000 008:00003 libselinux.so.1
00002b8b62e0b000       8 rw--- 00002b8b62e0b000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b62e0d000     112 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libaprutil-1.so.0.2.7
00002b8b62e29000    2044 ----- 000000000001c000 008:00003 libaprutil-1.so.0.2.7
00002b8b63028000       8 rw--- 000000000001b000 008:00003 libaprutil-1.so.0.2.7
00002b8b6302a000      36 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libcrypt-2.5.so
00002b8b63033000    2044 ----- 0000000000009000 008:00003 libcrypt-2.5.so
00002b8b63232000       4 r---- 0000000000008000 008:00003 libcrypt-2.5.so
00002b8b63233000       4 rw--- 0000000000009000 008:00003 libcrypt-2.5.so
00002b8b63234000     184 rw--- 00002b8b63234000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b63262000     224 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libldap-2.3.so.0.2.31
00002b8b6329a000    2048 ----- 0000000000038000 008:00003 libldap-2.3.so.0.2.31
00002b8b6349a000       8 rw--- 0000000000038000 008:00003 libldap-2.3.so.0.2.31
00002b8b6349c000       4 rw--- 00002b8b6349c000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b6349d000      52 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 liblber-2.3.so.0.2.31
00002b8b634aa000    2048 ----- 000000000000d000 008:00003 liblber-2.3.so.0.2.31
00002b8b636aa000       4 rw--- 000000000000d000 008:00003 liblber-2.3.so.0.2.31
00002b8b636ab000     964 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libdb-4.3.so
00002b8b6379c000    2044 ----- 00000000000f1000 008:00003 libdb-4.3.so
00002b8b6399b000      20 rw--- 00000000000f0000 008:00003 libdb-4.3.so
00002b8b639a0000     128 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libexpat.so.0.5.0
00002b8b639c0000    2044 ----- 0000000000020000 008:00003 libexpat.so.0.5.0
00002b8b63bbf000      12 rw--- 000000000001f000 008:00003 libexpat.so.0.5.0
00002b8b63bc2000       4 rw--- 00002b8b63bc2000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b63bc3000     152 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libapr-1.so.0.2.7
00002b8b63be9000    2048 ----- 0000000000026000 008:00003 libapr-1.so.0.2.7
00002b8b63de9000       4 rw--- 0000000000026000 008:00003 libapr-1.so.0.2.7
00002b8b63dea000      88 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libpthread-2.5.so
00002b8b63e00000    2044 ----- 0000000000016000 008:00003 libpthread-2.5.so
00002b8b63fff000       4 r---- 0000000000015000 008:00003 libpthread-2.5.so
00002b8b64000000       4 rw--- 0000000000016000 008:00003 libpthread-2.5.so
00002b8b64001000      16 rw--- 00002b8b64001000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b64005000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libdl-2.5.so
00002b8b64007000    2048 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 libdl-2.5.so
00002b8b64207000       4 r---- 0000000000002000 008:00003 libdl-2.5.so
00002b8b64208000       4 rw--- 0000000000003000 008:00003 libdl-2.5.so
00002b8b64209000       4 rw--- 00002b8b64209000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b6420a000    1328 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libc-2.5.so
00002b8b64356000    2048 ----- 000000000014c000 008:00003 libc-2.5.so
00002b8b64556000      16 r---- 000000000014c000 008:00003 libc-2.5.so
00002b8b6455a000       4 rw--- 0000000000150000 008:00003 libc-2.5.so
00002b8b6455b000      20 rw--- 00002b8b6455b000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b64560000     236 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libsepol.so.1
00002b8b6459b000    2048 ----- 000000000003b000 008:00003 libsepol.so.1
00002b8b6479b000       4 rw--- 000000000003b000 008:00003 libsepol.so.1
00002b8b6479c000      40 rw--- 00002b8b6479c000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b647a6000      12 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libuuid.so.1.2
00002b8b647a9000    2048 ----- 0000000000003000 008:00003 libuuid.so.1.2
00002b8b649a9000       4 rw--- 0000000000003000 008:00003 libuuid.so.1.2
00002b8b649aa000       4 rw--- 00002b8b649aa000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b649ab000     128 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libpq.so.4.1
00002b8b649cb000    2048 ----- 0000000000020000 008:00003 libpq.so.4.1
00002b8b64bcb000       8 rw--- 0000000000020000 008:00003 libpq.so.4.1
00002b8b64bcd000     352 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
00002b8b64c25000    2048 ----- 0000000000058000 008:00003 libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
00002b8b64e25000       8 rw--- 0000000000058000 008:00003 libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
00002b8b64e27000      68 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libresolv-2.5.so
00002b8b64e38000    2048 ----- 0000000000011000 008:00003 libresolv-2.5.so
00002b8b65038000       4 r---- 0000000000011000 008:00003 libresolv-2.5.so
00002b8b65039000       4 rw--- 0000000000012000 008:00003 libresolv-2.5.so
00002b8b6503a000      12 rw--- 00002b8b6503a000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b6503d000      96 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libsasl2.so.2.0.22
00002b8b65055000    2048 ----- 0000000000018000 008:00003 libsasl2.so.2.0.22
00002b8b65255000       4 rw--- 0000000000018000 008:00003 libsasl2.so.2.0.22
00002b8b65256000     272 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libssl.so.0.9.8e
00002b8b6529a000    2048 ----- 0000000000044000 008:00003 libssl.so.0.9.8e
00002b8b6549a000      24 rw--- 0000000000044000 008:00003 libssl.so.0.9.8e
00002b8b654a0000    1204 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
00002b8b655cd000    2044 ----- 000000000012d000 008:00003 libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
00002b8b657cc000     132 rw--- 000000000012c000 008:00003 libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
00002b8b657ed000      20 rw--- 00002b8b657ed000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b657f2000     580 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libkrb5.so.3.3
00002b8b65883000    2048 ----- 0000000000091000 008:00003 libkrb5.so.3.3
00002b8b65a83000      16 rw--- 0000000000091000 008:00003 libkrb5.so.3.3
00002b8b65a87000      84 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libnsl-2.5.so
00002b8b65a9c000    2044 ----- 0000000000015000 008:00003 libnsl-2.5.so
00002b8b65c9b000       4 r---- 0000000000014000 008:00003 libnsl-2.5.so
00002b8b65c9c000       4 rw--- 0000000000015000 008:00003 libnsl-2.5.so
00002b8b65c9d000      12 rw--- 00002b8b65c9d000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b65ca0000     176 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
00002b8b65ccc000    2048 ----- 000000000002c000 008:00003 libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
00002b8b65ecc000       8 rw--- 000000000002c000 008:00003 libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
00002b8b65ece000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libcom_err.so.2.1
00002b8b65ed0000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 libcom_err.so.2.1
00002b8b660cf000       4 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 libcom_err.so.2.1
00002b8b660d0000     144 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libk5crypto.so.3.1
00002b8b660f4000    2044 ----- 0000000000024000 008:00003 libk5crypto.so.3.1
00002b8b662f3000       8 rw--- 0000000000023000 008:00003 libk5crypto.so.3.1
00002b8b662f5000       4 rw--- 00002b8b662f5000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b662f6000      80 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libz.so.1.2.3
00002b8b6630a000    2044 ----- 0000000000014000 008:00003 libz.so.1.2.3
00002b8b66509000       4 rw--- 0000000000013000 008:00003 libz.so.1.2.3
00002b8b6650a000      32 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libkrb5support.so.0.1
00002b8b66512000    2044 ----- 0000000000008000 008:00003 libkrb5support.so.0.1
00002b8b66711000       4 rw--- 0000000000007000 008:00003 libkrb5support.so.0.1
00002b8b66712000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libkeyutils-1.2.so
00002b8b66714000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 libkeyutils-1.2.so
00002b8b66913000       4 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 libkeyutils-1.2.so
00002b8b66914000      12 rw--- 00002b8b66914000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b66917000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_auth_basic.so
00002b8b66919000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_auth_basic.so
00002b8b66b18000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_auth_basic.so
00002b8b66b1a000      24 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_auth_digest.so
00002b8b66b20000    2044 ----- 0000000000006000 008:00003 mod_auth_digest.so
00002b8b66d1f000       8 rw--- 0000000000005000 008:00003 mod_auth_digest.so
00002b8b66d21000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authn_file.so
00002b8b66d23000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_authn_file.so
00002b8b66f22000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_authn_file.so
00002b8b66f24000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authn_alias.so
00002b8b66f26000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_authn_alias.so
00002b8b67125000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_authn_alias.so
00002b8b67127000       4 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authn_anon.so
00002b8b67128000    2048 ----- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_authn_anon.so
00002b8b67328000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_authn_anon.so
00002b8b6732a000       4 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authn_dbm.so
00002b8b6732b000    2048 ----- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_authn_dbm.so
00002b8b6752b000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_authn_dbm.so
00002b8b6752d000       4 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authn_default.so
00002b8b6752e000    2044 ----- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_authn_default.so
00002b8b6772d000       8 rw--- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authn_default.so
00002b8b6772f000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authz_host.so
00002b8b67731000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_authz_host.so
00002b8b67930000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_authz_host.so
00002b8b67932000       4 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authz_user.so
00002b8b67933000    2044 ----- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_authz_user.so
00002b8b67b32000       8 rw--- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authz_user.so
00002b8b67b34000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authz_owner.so
00002b8b67b36000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_authz_owner.so
00002b8b67d35000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_authz_owner.so
00002b8b67d37000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authz_groupfile.so
00002b8b67d39000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_authz_groupfile.so
00002b8b67f38000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_authz_groupfile.so
00002b8b67f3a000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authz_dbm.so
00002b8b67f3c000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_authz_dbm.so
00002b8b6813b000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_authz_dbm.so
00002b8b6813d000       4 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authz_default.so
00002b8b6813e000    2044 ----- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_authz_default.so
00002b8b6833d000       8 rw--- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authz_default.so
00002b8b6833f000      44 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_ldap.so
00002b8b6834a000    2048 ----- 000000000000b000 008:00003 mod_ldap.so
00002b8b6854a000       8 rw--- 000000000000b000 008:00003 mod_ldap.so
00002b8b6854c000      24 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_authnz_ldap.so
00002b8b68552000    2044 ----- 0000000000006000 008:00003 mod_authnz_ldap.so
00002b8b68751000       8 rw--- 0000000000005000 008:00003 mod_authnz_ldap.so
00002b8b68753000      36 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_include.so
00002b8b6875c000    2048 ----- 0000000000009000 008:00003 mod_include.so
00002b8b6895c000       8 rw--- 0000000000009000 008:00003 mod_include.so
00002b8b6895e000      20 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_log_config.so
00002b8b68963000    2044 ----- 0000000000005000 008:00003 mod_log_config.so
00002b8b68b62000       8 rw--- 0000000000004000 008:00003 mod_log_config.so
00002b8b68b64000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_logio.so
00002b8b68b66000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_logio.so
00002b8b68d65000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_logio.so
00002b8b68d67000       4 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_env.so
00002b8b68d68000    2048 ----- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_env.so
00002b8b68f68000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_env.so
00002b8b68f6a000      16 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_ext_filter.so
00002b8b68f6e000    2044 ----- 0000000000004000 008:00003 mod_ext_filter.so
00002b8b6916d000       8 rw--- 0000000000003000 008:00003 mod_ext_filter.so
00002b8b6916f000      20 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_mime_magic.so
00002b8b69174000    2044 ----- 0000000000005000 008:00003 mod_mime_magic.so
00002b8b69373000       8 rw--- 0000000000004000 008:00003 mod_mime_magic.so
00002b8b69375000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_expires.so
00002b8b69377000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_expires.so
00002b8b69576000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_expires.so
00002b8b69578000      16 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_deflate.so
00002b8b6957c000    2044 ----- 0000000000004000 008:00003 mod_deflate.so
00002b8b6977b000       8 rw--- 0000000000003000 008:00003 mod_deflate.so
00002b8b6977d000      12 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_headers.so
00002b8b69780000    2048 ----- 0000000000003000 008:00003 mod_headers.so
00002b8b69980000       8 rw--- 0000000000003000 008:00003 mod_headers.so
00002b8b69982000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_usertrack.so
00002b8b69984000    2048 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_usertrack.so
00002b8b69b84000       8 rw--- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_usertrack.so
00002b8b69b86000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_setenvif.so
00002b8b69b88000    2048 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_setenvif.so
00002b8b69d88000       8 rw--- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_setenvif.so
00002b8b69d8a000      16 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_mime.so
00002b8b69d8e000    2044 ----- 0000000000004000 008:00003 mod_mime.so
00002b8b69f8d000       8 rw--- 0000000000003000 008:00003 mod_mime.so
00002b8b69f8f000      84 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_dav.so
00002b8b69fa4000    2044 ----- 0000000000015000 008:00003 mod_dav.so
00002b8b6a1a3000       8 rw--- 0000000000014000 008:00003 mod_dav.so
00002b8b6a1a5000      16 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_status.so
00002b8b6a1a9000    2044 ----- 0000000000004000 008:00003 mod_status.so
00002b8b6a3a8000       8 rw--- 0000000000003000 008:00003 mod_status.so
00002b8b6a3aa000      32 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_autoindex.so
00002b8b6a3b2000    2044 ----- 0000000000008000 008:00003 mod_autoindex.so
00002b8b6a5b1000       8 rw--- 0000000000007000 008:00003 mod_autoindex.so
00002b8b6a5b3000      16 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_info.so
00002b8b6a5b7000    2044 ----- 0000000000004000 008:00003 mod_info.so
00002b8b6a7b6000       8 rw--- 0000000000003000 008:00003 mod_info.so
00002b8b6a7b8000      44 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_dav_fs.so
00002b8b6a7c3000    2044 ----- 000000000000b000 008:00003 mod_dav_fs.so
00002b8b6a9c2000       8 rw--- 000000000000a000 008:00003 mod_dav_fs.so
00002b8b6a9c4000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_vhost_alias.so
00002b8b6a9c6000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_vhost_alias.so
00002b8b6abc5000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_vhost_alias.so
00002b8b6abc7000      28 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_negotiation.so
00002b8b6abce000    2044 ----- 0000000000007000 008:00003 mod_negotiation.so
00002b8b6adcd000       8 rw--- 0000000000006000 008:00003 mod_negotiation.so
00002b8b6adcf000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_dir.so
00002b8b6add1000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_dir.so
00002b8b6afd0000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_dir.so
00002b8b6afd2000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_actions.so
00002b8b6afd4000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_actions.so
00002b8b6b1d3000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_actions.so
00002b8b6b1d5000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_speling.so
00002b8b6b1d7000    2048 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_speling.so
00002b8b6b3d7000       8 rw--- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_speling.so
00002b8b6b3d9000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_userdir.so
00002b8b6b3db000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_userdir.so
00002b8b6b5da000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_userdir.so
00002b8b6b5dc000      12 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_alias.so
00002b8b6b5df000    2044 ----- 0000000000003000 008:00003 mod_alias.so
00002b8b6b7de000       8 rw--- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_alias.so
00002b8b6b7e0000      56 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_rewrite.so
00002b8b6b7ee000    2044 ----- 000000000000e000 008:00003 mod_rewrite.so
00002b8b6b9ed000       8 rw--- 000000000000d000 008:00003 mod_rewrite.so
00002b8b6b9ef000      72 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_proxy.so
00002b8b6ba01000    2044 ----- 0000000000012000 008:00003 mod_proxy.so
00002b8b6bc00000       8 rw--- 0000000000011000 008:00003 mod_proxy.so
00002b8b6bc02000      20 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_proxy_balancer.so
00002b8b6bc07000    2044 ----- 0000000000005000 008:00003 mod_proxy_balancer.so
00002b8b6be06000       8 rw--- 0000000000004000 008:00003 mod_proxy_balancer.so
00002b8b6be08000      28 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_proxy_ftp.so
00002b8b6be0f000    2044 ----- 0000000000007000 008:00003 mod_proxy_ftp.so
00002b8b6c00e000       8 rw--- 0000000000006000 008:00003 mod_proxy_ftp.so
00002b8b6c010000      28 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_proxy_http.so
00002b8b6c017000    2044 ----- 0000000000007000 008:00003 mod_proxy_http.so
00002b8b6c216000       8 rw--- 0000000000006000 008:00003 mod_proxy_http.so
00002b8b6c218000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_proxy_connect.so
00002b8b6c21a000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_proxy_connect.so
00002b8b6c419000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_proxy_connect.so
00002b8b6c41b000      28 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_cache.so
00002b8b6c422000    2044 ----- 0000000000007000 008:00003 mod_cache.so
00002b8b6c621000       8 rw--- 0000000000006000 008:00003 mod_cache.so
00002b8b6c623000       4 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_suexec.so
00002b8b6c624000    2048 ----- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_suexec.so
00002b8b6c824000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_suexec.so
00002b8b6c826000      16 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_disk_cache.so
00002b8b6c82a000    2048 ----- 0000000000004000 008:00003 mod_disk_cache.so
00002b8b6ca2a000       8 rw--- 0000000000004000 008:00003 mod_disk_cache.so
00002b8b6ca2c000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_file_cache.so
00002b8b6ca2e000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_file_cache.so
00002b8b6cc2d000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_file_cache.so
00002b8b6cc2f000      24 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_mem_cache.so
00002b8b6cc35000    2044 ----- 0000000000006000 008:00003 mod_mem_cache.so
00002b8b6ce34000       8 rw--- 0000000000005000 008:00003 mod_mem_cache.so
00002b8b6ce36000      20 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_cgi.so
00002b8b6ce3b000    2048 ----- 0000000000005000 008:00003 mod_cgi.so
00002b8b6d03b000       8 rw--- 0000000000005000 008:00003 mod_cgi.so
00002b8b6d03d000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_version.so
00002b8b6d03f000    2044 ----- 0000000000002000 008:00003 mod_version.so
00002b8b6d23e000       8 rw--- 0000000000001000 008:00003 mod_version.so
00002b8b6d240000    3180 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libphp5.so
00002b8b6d55b000    2044 ----- 000000000031b000 008:00003 libphp5.so
00002b8b6d75a000     288 rw--- 000000000031a000 008:00003 libphp5.so
00002b8b6d7a2000      32 rw--- 00002b8b6d7a2000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b6d7af000     224 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libgmp.so.3.3.3
00002b8b6d7e7000    2048 ----- 0000000000038000 008:00003 libgmp.so.3.3.3
00002b8b6d9e7000       4 rw--- 0000000000038000 008:00003 libgmp.so.3.3.3
00002b8b6d9e8000      60 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libbz2.so.1.0.3
00002b8b6d9f7000    2044 ----- 000000000000f000 008:00003 libbz2.so.1.0.3
00002b8b6dbf6000       8 rw--- 000000000000e000 008:00003 libbz2.so.1.0.3
00002b8b6dbf8000    1228 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libxml2.so.2.6.26
00002b8b6dd2b000    2048 ----- 0000000000133000 008:00003 libxml2.so.2.6.26
00002b8b6df2b000      36 rw--- 0000000000133000 008:00003 libxml2.so.2.6.26
00002b8b6df34000       4 rw--- 00002b8b6df34000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b6df35000      32 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mod_proxy_ajp.so
00002b8b6df3d000    2044 ----- 0000000000008000 008:00003 mod_proxy_ajp.so
00002b8b6e13c000       8 rw--- 0000000000007000 008:00003 mod_proxy_ajp.so
00002b8b6e143000      40 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libnss_files-2.5.so
00002b8b6e14d000    2044 ----- 000000000000a000 008:00003 libnss_files-2.5.so
00002b8b6e34c000       4 r---- 0000000000009000 008:00003 libnss_files-2.5.so
00002b8b6e34d000       4 rw--- 000000000000a000 008:00003 libnss_files-2.5.so
00002b8b6e34e000      84 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 apc.so
00002b8b6e363000    2048 ----- 0000000000015000 008:00003 apc.so
00002b8b6e563000       8 rw--- 0000000000015000 008:00003 apc.so
00002b8b6e565000      32 rw--- 00002b8b6e565000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b6e572000      28 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 librt-2.5.so
00002b8b6e579000    2048 ----- 0000000000007000 008:00003 librt-2.5.so
00002b8b6e779000       4 r---- 0000000000007000 008:00003 librt-2.5.so
00002b8b6e77a000       4 rw--- 0000000000008000 008:00003 librt-2.5.so
00002b8b6e77b000      56 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 curl.so
00002b8b6e789000    2044 ----- 000000000000e000 008:00003 curl.so
00002b8b6e988000       8 rw--- 000000000000d000 008:00003 curl.so
00002b8b6e98f000     236 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libcurl.so.3.0.0
00002b8b6e9ca000    2048 ----- 000000000003b000 008:00003 libcurl.so.3.0.0
00002b8b6ebca000       8 rw--- 000000000003b000 008:00003 libcurl.so.3.0.0
00002b8b6ebcc000     196 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libidn.so.11.5.19
00002b8b6ebfd000    2044 ----- 0000000000031000 008:00003 libidn.so.11.5.19
00002b8b6edfc000       4 rw--- 0000000000030000 008:00003 libidn.so.11.5.19
00002b8b6edfd000      28 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 dbase.so
00002b8b6ee04000    2048 ----- 0000000000007000 008:00003 dbase.so
00002b8b6f004000       4 rw--- 0000000000007000 008:00003 dbase.so
00002b8b6f005000     156 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 dom.so
00002b8b6f02c000    2044 ----- 0000000000027000 008:00003 dom.so
00002b8b6f22b000      24 rw--- 0000000000026000 008:00003 dom.so
00002b8b6f231000       4 rw--- 00002b8b6f231000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b6f232000      28 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 json.so
00002b8b6f239000    2044 ----- 0000000000007000 008:00003 json.so
00002b8b6f438000       4 rw--- 0000000000006000 008:00003 json.so
00002b8b6f439000    1944 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mbstring.so
00002b8b6f61f000    2048 ----- 00000000001e6000 008:00003 mbstring.so
00002b8b6f81f000      36 rw--- 00000000001e6000 008:00003 mbstring.so
00002b8b6f828000      44 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mysql.so
00002b8b6f833000    2044 ----- 000000000000b000 008:00003 mysql.so
00002b8b6fa32000       8 rw--- 000000000000a000 008:00003 mysql.so
00002b8b6fa39000    1220 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
00002b8b6fb6a000    2044 ----- 0000000000131000 008:00003 libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
00002b8b6fd69000     308 rw--- 0000000000130000 008:00003 libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
00002b8b6fdb6000       4 rw--- 00002b8b6fdb6000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b6fdb7000     104 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 mysqli.so
00002b8b6fdd1000    2044 ----- 000000000001a000 008:00003 mysqli.so
00002b8b6ffd0000      12 rw--- 0000000000019000 008:00003 mysqli.so
00002b8b6ffd3000       4 rw--- 00002b8b6ffd3000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00002b8b6ffd4000      88 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 pdo.so
00002b8b6ffea000    2048 ----- 0000000000016000 008:00003 pdo.so
00002b8b701ea000      12 rw--- 0000000000016000 008:00003 pdo.so
00002b8b701ed000      24 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 pdo_mysql.so
00002b8b701f3000    2048 ----- 0000000000006000 008:00003 pdo_mysql.so
00002b8b703f3000       4 rw--- 0000000000006000 008:00003 pdo_mysql.so
00002b8b703f4000      20 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 pdo_sqlite.so
00002b8b703f9000    2048 ----- 0000000000005000 008:00003 pdo_sqlite.so
00002b8b705f9000       4 rw--- 0000000000005000 008:00003 pdo_sqlite.so
00002b8b705fa000      64 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 sqlite.so
00002b8b7060a000    2044 ----- 0000000000010000 008:00003 sqlite.so
00002b8b70809000       8 rw--- 000000000000f000 008:00003 sqlite.so
00002b8b70810000     284 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libsqlite.so.0.8.6
00002b8b70857000    2044 ----- 0000000000047000 008:00003 libsqlite.so.0.8.6
00002b8b70a56000      12 rw--- 0000000000046000 008:00003 libsqlite.so.0.8.6
00002b8b70a59000      28 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 wddx.so
00002b8b70a60000    2048 ----- 0000000000007000 008:00003 wddx.so
00002b8b70c60000       4 rw--- 0000000000007000 008:00003 wddx.so
00002b8b70c61000      28 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 xmlreader.so
00002b8b70c68000    2044 ----- 0000000000007000 008:00003 xmlreader.so
00002b8b70e67000       8 rw--- 0000000000006000 008:00003 xmlreader.so
00002b8b70e69000      28 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 xmlwriter.so
00002b8b70e70000    2044 ----- 0000000000007000 008:00003 xmlwriter.so
00002b8b7106f000       8 rw--- 0000000000006000 008:00003 xmlwriter.so
00002b8b71071000      28 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 xsl.so
00002b8b71078000    2044 ----- 0000000000007000 008:00003 xsl.so
00002b8b71277000       4 rw--- 0000000000006000 008:00003 xsl.so
00002b8b7127d000      68 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00003 libexslt.so.0.8.13
00002b8b7128e000    2048 ----- 0000000000011000 008:00003 libexslt.so.0.8.13
00002b8b7148e000       4 rw--- 0000000000011000 008:00003 libexslt.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the default http.conf (or very close to it) is actually usually a good thing.  You'd be surprised how much better at this apache developers and redhat engineers are than most of us :)

First off, and I apologize if this sounds dumb, but are you certain that nginx is configured *in front* of apache?  I can't tell you how many times I've seen people read a blog post recommending nginx and gone and setup their existing apache's to mod_proxy /images back to nginx.

Second, most apache modules, especially the ones that come in a redhat/centos build, are very well written to use shared libraries and the apr runtime, so they're not likely to buy you much commenting them out.

I think the biggest thing you probably want to look at is a php op cache.   It can have a dramatic affect on both the performance and the burst-memory-usage of php scripts.  Fortunatly as a CentOS user you can setup the EPEL repo and "yum install php-pecl-apc" and have it setup in moments.  See how that helps.

Comment: Hey Cagenut, thanks for the comment - I did configure nginx in front of apache, meaning that all traffic passes through ngninx. static content are being served by nginx, the dynamic content is being served by nginx after requesting it by apache (currently nginx is on port 80 and apache 8080), I also installed apc long time ago using pecl.
Any more tips?